# Performing test for homogeneity of variance without samples

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, anova, heteroscedasticity

I'd like to perform a test for homogeneity of variance in r, but I don't have samples available to test.

I have the sample mean of each group, the sample deviation of each group, and the sample size of each group(100).

```
Brand    ybar_i  s_i    n_i
---------------------------
LowTar   9.64    .291   100
A        10.22   .478   100
B        10.77   .372   100
C        11.57   .352   100
D        13.59   .469   100
```

I'm thinking I should use the Levene test from Lawstat package, but that requires samples to test.  Or I think I could use the Fmax test. but that also requires samples.

Comment: When you say you have the "sample deviation" are you referring to sample *standard deviation*, or to *mean deviation* or to something else? Fmax doesn't require samples, (A particular implementation of it might but you can calculate it easily by hand)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of a software package shouldn't be necessary to solve this problem- you have all the necessary information given to you.

You can use Hartley's F max test to test 
$H_0 = \sigma_a = \sigma_b = \sigma_c = \sigma_d $ vs.
$H_A$ = population variances are not equal.

You are given the sample deviation from each group, so you have enough information to calculate a test statistic:

$ F_{max} = \frac{\sigma_{max}^2 }{\sigma_{min}^2}  = \frac{0.478^2}{0.291^2}$ = 2.6982

Now all that is left is to compare the test statistic to the tabulated critical values for the Hartley test using $df_2 = 100-1 = 99 $ and $t=4$

If the test statistic exceeds the tabulated F value, reject $H_0$.

Documentation including tabulated values can easily be found: http://archive.bio.ed.ac.uk/jdeacon/statistics/table8.htm

Comment: This is correct, but you should note that Hartley's test is very sensitive to the normality of the data. Thus, you need to make a leap of faith to apply this.

Comment: Indeed, since we don't have data we can't even assess normality, so it makes the leap of faith a blind one.